# How to avoid code duplication when comparing two enums' variants and their values?

Tags: enums, rust, comparison

I need to compare two [`serde_json::Value`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1.0.38/serde_json/enum.Value.html)s:

```
enum Value {
    Null,
    Bool(bool),
    Number(Number),
    String(String),
    Array(Vec<Value>),
    Object(Map<String, Value>),
}
```

The comparison will return another enum:

```
enum Diff {
    Equal,
    Different,
    NotFound,
}
```

I started writing the code structured as follow:

```
fn compare(val1: &Value, val2: &Value) {
    let cmp = match val1 {
        Value::Null => {
            if let Value::Null = val2 {
                Diff::Equal
            } else {
                Diff::NotFound
            }
        }
        Value::Bool(b1) => {
            if let Value::Bool(b2) = val2 {
                if b1 == b2 {
                    Diff::Equal
                } else {
                    Diff::Different
                }
            } else {
                Diff::NotFound
            }
        }
        Value::Number(ref n1) => {
            if let Value::Number(ref n2) = val2 {
                if n1 == n2 {
                    Diff::Equal
                } else {
                    Diff::Different
                }
            } else {
                Diff::NotFound
            }
        }
        Value::String(ref s1) => {
            if let Value::String(ref s2) = val2 {
                if s1 == s2 {
                    Diff::Equal
                } else {
                    Diff::Different
                }
            } else {
                Diff::NotFound
            }
        }
        _ => {
            // etc...
            Diff::NotFound
        }
    };

}
```

There is a lot of code duplication that I'd like to avoid.

1. Is there a better way to compare enums in general?
2. How can I avoid this type of duplication (in C++ you could use macro for example)

Comment: Can you describe what the function should do? It seems like you return `Equal` when the values are equal, `Different` when the values are different but with the same variant, and `NotFound` when the variants are different, which seems to be a weird name. Can you confirm?

Comment: @mcarton Yes, you are correct, `NotFound` is a bad name, but basically I want to distinguish when the two JSON nodes 1) have the same key and value, 2) have the same key but different value, 3) have the same key but different type/variant (ex first is a number and second is a string), 4) (not in the code yet) a key in node1 does not exist in node2 and vice-versa.

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d9286f0e6564ac46c20398a2664fabfa, you could do that and implement it with a macro.

Comment: You could `#[derive(PartialEq)]` and in case of non equality you could do another check. Would help you to get the "correct" checks away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match against 2 values simultaneously:

```
let cmp = match (val1, val2) {
    (Value::Null, Value::Null) => Diff::Equal,
    _ => {
        // etc...
        Diff::NotFound
    }
};
```

You can also implement a conversion function or trait and use it:

```
impl Diff {
    fn new<T: PartialEq>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Diff {
        if lhs == rhs { Diff::Equal } else { Diff::Different }
    }
}

fn compare(val1: &Value, val2: &Value) {
    let cmp = match (val1, val2) {
        (Value::Null, Value::Null) => Diff::Equal,
        (Value::Bool(b1), Value::Bool(b2)) => Diff::new(b1, b2),
        _ => Diff::NotFound,
    };
}
```